# Gatsby: Unable to Import Component with Graph Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to write component which queries my CMS for a list of tags nd builds a count of the top 6 tags and outputs them as clickable links. This is what I have so far:

```js
import { graphql, StaticQuery, Link } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout"
import kebabCase from "lodash/kebabCase"
const _ = require("lodash")


const TopTools = props => {
  const toolNodes = props.data.portfolio.nodes
  let tags = []
  let tools = []
  toolNodes.map(toolNode => tags.push(...toolNode.tools))
  tags = tags.concat(tools)
  const x = tags.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ((acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1), acc),
    {}
  )
  let toptools = []
  for (let tool in x) {
    toptools .push([tool, x[tool]])
  }
  toptools = toptools .sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1]
  })
  toptools = toptools.slice(0, 6)
 
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        {toptools.map((tag, i) => [
          <Link to={`/tools/${kebabCase(tag[0])}/`}>
                <h4>
                  {tag[0]}
                </h4>
          </Link>,
        ])}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default TopTools;
export const query = graphql`
  {
    portfolio: allContentfulPortfolio {
      nodes {
        tools
      }
    }
  }
`
```

When I try to import this into my page like so:

```
import TopTools from "../components/TopTools"
```

and use it:

```
<TopTools/>
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'portfolio' of undefined
TopTools
   5 | const _ = require("lodash")
   6 | 
   7 | const TopTools = props => {
>  8 |   const toolNodes = props.data.portfolio.nodes
   9 |   let tags = []
  10 |   let tools = []
  11 |   toolNodes.map(toolNode => tags.push(...toolNode.tools))
```

I don't understand why this happening? I made this script into a 'page' of its own and I could see the links being output. Why does this not work when I try to import it as a component? Am I not using GraphQL queries right?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using [useStaticQuery](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2019-02-20-introducing-use-static-query/). I reshaped the script as follows:

```js
import { graphql, Link , useStaticQuery} from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout"
import kebabCase from "lodash/kebabCase"
const _ = require("lodash")

const Top = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
  allContentfulPortfolio {
    nodes {
      tools
    }
  }
}
  `)
  const toolNodes = data.allContentfulPortfolio.nodes
  let tags = []
  let tools = []
  toolNodes.map(toolNode => tags.push(...toolNode.tools))
  tags = tags.concat(tools)
  const x = tags.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => ((acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1), acc),
    {}
  )
  let sortable = []
  for (let tool in x) {
    sortable.push([tool, x[tool]])
  }
  sortable = sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1]
  })
  sortable = sortable.slice(0, 6)
  return (
    <div>
      {sortable.map((tag, i) => [
        <Link to={`/tools/${kebabCase(tag[0])}/`}>
              <h4>
                {tag[0]}
              </h4>
        </Link>,
      ])}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Top;
```